# Accessing table of record type from dynamic SQL

Tags: oracle, types, record

I need to store some data in a indexed temporary table inside an oracle procedure (version = 12.1.0.2) for several operations on it. Code is:

```
declare

TYPE CUR_TABLE            IS REF CURSOR;
C_TABLE                   CUR_TABLE;

TYPE REC_TRASF  IS RECORD (F1 NUMBER(4,0), F2 NUMBER(7,0));
TYPE TABLE_TRASF          IS TABLE OF REC_TRASF INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
TAB_TRASF TABLE_TRASF;

BEGIN
    OPEN C_TABLE FOR 'SELECT 1 AS F1, 2 AS F2 FROM DUAL';
        LOOP
            FETCH C_TABLE BULK COLLECT INTO TAB_TRASF ;
           EXIT WHEN C_TABLE%NOTFOUND;
        END LOOP; 
    CLOSE C_TABLE;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select * from TABLE(TAB_TRASF)'; /*just to test if table is accessible*/
END;
```

But when I execute this block I get: ORA-00904: "TAB_TRASF": invalid identifier.

1. How to access table of record type from dynamic SQL?
2. Is there any other best practice to store data in indexed temporary tables inside a procedure?

Edit: this is just an example of my real procedure. Anyway, I have two requirements: first, TAB_TRASF must be populated with CUR_TABLE cursor; second, I can only use dynamic SQL to access TAB_TRASF and to make several other operations with its data.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL at all, but particularly for the last select? What do you ultimately plan to do with the data in `TAB_TRASF` - how will you use that really, in a SQL context or only in a PL/SQL context? (Also 'temporary table' means something else; you have a PL/SQL table/collection.)

Answer (score 4):

You can't use a PL/SQL table like that in a SQL context. Ignoring the scope issue that is causing your current error (the dynamic SQL context has no visibility of your local PL/SQL variables) that wouldn't work statically either:

```
    ...
    OPEN c_table FOR
        select * from TABLE(TAB_TRASF);
END;
/
```

would get this instead:

```
ORA-06550: line 18, column 29:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 18, column 23:
PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
```

You can iterate over the collection:

```
...
    FOR i IN TAB_TRASF.FIRST..TAB_TRASF.LAST LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('i: ' || i
            || ' f1: ' || TAB_TRASF(i).f1
            || ' f2: ' || TAB_TRASF(i).f2);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

which gets:

```
i: 1 f1: 1 f2: 2


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

But if you want to use the contents of the collection in SQL, e.g. joining to it, then you either have to have a object/table types declares at schema level (instead of record/collection types in PL/SQL), or a global temporary table created at schema level, as a permanent object.

Incidentally, you don't need dynamic SQL for the first part of your code either, or the loop; you can simplify that to:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE REC_TRASF IS RECORD (F1 NUMBER(4,0), F2 NUMBER(7,0));
    TYPE TABLE_TRASF IS TABLE OF REC_TRASF INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
    TAB_TRASF TABLE_TRASF;
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 AS F1, 2 AS F2
    BULK COLLECT INTO TAB_TRASF
    FROM DUAL;

    FOR i IN TAB_TRASF.FIRST..TAB_TRASF.LAST LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('i: ' || i
            || ' f1: ' || TAB_TRASF(i).f1
            || ' f2: ' || TAB_TRASF(i).f2);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. Dynamic sql is required in my case (please do not consider my code as a real case, it is just a basic example of my real procedure, which uses this table to make some other sql operations, depending on certain conditions). I don't know how to access my table in dynamic sql, and I have to use dynamic sql.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store temporary data in an indexed `temporary table` then you need to create `GTT` and index should be created on required columns.

You can then use that `GTT` in any of your code-block and your code will be simplified much.

See the example below:

```
SET SERVEROUT ON

-- CREATE TEMP TABLE
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TABLE (
    F1   NUMBER(4, 0),
    F2   NUMBER(7, 0)
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;



-- CREATE INDEX ON REQUIRED COLUMN
CREATE INDEX TEMP_TABLE_INDX01 ON TEMP_TABLE(F1);



-- YOUR CODE BLOCK STARTS FROM HERE


--DECLARE
--    TYPE CUR_TABLE IS REF CURSOR;
--    C_TABLE     CUR_TABLE;
--    TYPE REC_TRASF IS RECORD (
--        F1          NUMBER(4, 0),
--        F2          NUMBER(7, 0)
--    );
--    TYPE TABLE_TRASF IS
--        TABLE OF REC_TRASF INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
--    TAB_TRASF   TABLE_TRASF;
BEGIN
--    OPEN C_TABLE FOR 'SELECT 1 AS F1, 2 AS F2 FROM DUAL';

--    LOOP
--        EXIT WHEN C_TABLE%NOTFOUND;
--        FETCH C_TABLE BULK COLLECT INTO TAB_TRASF;
--        FORALL I IN 1..TAB_TRASF.COUNT
        INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE 
        SELECT 1 AS F1, 2 AS F2 FROM DUAL;
--    END LOOP;
--    CLOSE C_TABLE;
    FOR I IN (SELECT F1, F2 FROM TEMP_TABLE) LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('F1: ' || I.F1);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('F2: ' || I.F2);
    END LOOP;
    --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select * from TABLE(TAB_TRASF)'; /*just to test if table is accessible*/
END;
/

-- output --


F1: 1
F2: 2


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

This is a simple example of using a temp table.

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9c8a4ab76bed6c3feca0487564e390ce)

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `TABLE()` expression with an associative array (or index-by table). You have to define type as `TABLE_TRASF IS TABLE OF REC_TRASF` and it has to be created on schema level, not as local type.

It is possible to use it dynamically, although I doubt that you would really need dynamic SQL. Most likely you can work with static SQL.

Would be one of these:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE F_NUMBER AS OBJECT (
    F1 NUMBER, 
    F2 NUMBER 
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE F_NUMBER_TABLE AS TABLE OF F_NUMBER;

DECLARE

    number_table F_NUMBER_TABLE;
    number_table_new F_NUMBER_TABLE;
    F1 NUMBER; 
    F2 NUMBER; 

    TYPE f_array_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
    f1_array f_array_type;
    f2_array f_array_type;

BEGIN

    number_table := F_NUMBER_TABLE(F_NUMBER(2,3));

    SELECT * 
    INTO f1, f2
    FROM TABLE(number_table);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'f1 = ' || F1 );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'f2 = ' || F2 );

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select * from TABLE(:t)' INTO F1, F2 USING number_table;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'f1 = ' || f1 );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'f2 = ' || f2 );


    number_table := F_NUMBER_TABLE(F_NUMBER(2,3), F_NUMBER(22,33));

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select * from TABLE(:t)' BULK COLLECT INTO f1_array, f2_array USING number_table;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'f1_array(*) = ' || f1_array(1) ||','|| f1_array(2) );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'f2_array(*) = ' || f2_array(1) ||','|| f2_array(2) );

    SELECT F_NUMBER(F1, F2)
    BULK COLLECT INTO number_table_new
    FROM TABLE(number_table);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'number_table_new(1) = ' || number_table_new(1).F1 ||','|| number_table_new(1).F2 );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'number_table_new(2) = ' || number_table_new(2).F1 ||','|| number_table_new(2).F2 );

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select F_NUMBER(F1, F2) from TABLE(:t)' BULK COLLECT INTO number_table_new USING number_table;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'number_table_new(1) = ' || number_table_new(1).F1 ||','|| number_table_new(1).F2 );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'number_table_new(2) = ' || number_table_new(2).F1 ||','|| number_table_new(2).F2 );

END;
```